# Store the result of a select statement within a stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, teradata

This is a Teradata v14 specific question.

How to store the result of a query within a stored procedure for further processing.

Options I have looked at:

- volatile temporary table - but that needs to be created prior to stored
  procedure
- derived table - but it only holds the result for the duration of one query

The result needs to be available for the duration of the stored procedure.

Are there any other options?

Update 16 June 2014:
Based on the answers and comments it seems that volatile table is the best answer. However then we try to use volatile table the stored procedure complains that the table doesn't exist. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Do you mean you want to store the data for further processing inside your proc?  What do you mean the volatile table would need to be created prior to the procedure?  You would just declare the table inside the procedure.

Comment: @Andrew: yes, I mean I want to do the processing within the stored procedure. The stored procedure could be executed more than once at the same time. Declaring the volatile table inside the stored procedure throws an error saying that the table doesn't exist.

Comment: No, a Volatile Table is not the best answer. Use a Global Temporary Table as Rob suggested. Create it **once** before you create your SP (you can also create it from within your SP and catch the "table already exists" error, but it's not worth the overhead in source code), within your SP you simply use it like any other table, each session will have it's own materialized instance.

Comment: @dnoeth: thanks, does the global temporary table exist within the Schema or across all schemas on the server? Why is it better than a permanent table?

Comment: The definition of a GTT is stored within a database exactly like a permanent table. But each permanent table needs a unique name, while each session can insert different data into the same GTT. And you don't have to drop the table, the session's version of the GTT is automatically dropped during logoff like a Volatile Table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered a global temporary table?

The table definition is stored in the DBC data dictionary and instantiated for the duration of the session when referenced by SQL. Like a volatile table the global temporary table is session specific. Unlike a volatile table, a global temporary table relies on the user's temporary space instead of spool space.

Comment: thanks, I have but creating the table from within the stored procedure seems to throw an error saying that the table doesn't exist. Also what would happen if the stored procedure was kicked off several times at the same time? (not necessarily in the same session)

Comment: I apologize if my response wasn't clear - Create the global temporary table outside the stored procedure. Then you can simply reference it in your stored procedure as needed.

Comment: Each "instance" of the GTT is session specific, so if multiple users execute the proc concurrently, they'll each have a separate instance of the GTT.