# Reffering to created volatile table causes NOT exists error in procedure

Tags: sql, teradata, exists

This is really strange error for me, because I can't even recreate previously created procedure:

Next code works:

```
 REPLACE PROCEDURE prd2.SP_temp_not_working()
    begin
        declare V_REPORT_DATE   int;
            CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE VT_C,
            NO FALLBACK,
            NO LOG
        (
        REPORT_DATE DATE FORMAT 'YY/MM/DD' NOT NULL
    )
    UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX( REPORT_DATE )
    ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
    l1:
    FOR RD AS RD_CURS CURSOR FOR
            SELECT 1  from VT_C
        DO
        SET V_REPORT_DATE =1 ;
    end for l1;
end;
```

But this isn't working

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE prd2.SP_temp_working()
begin
    declare V_REPORT_DATE   int;
        CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE VT_C,
        NO FALLBACK,
        NO LOG
    (
    REPORT_DATE DATE FORMAT 'YY/MM/DD' NOT NULL
)
UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX( REPORT_DATE )
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
l1:
FOR RD AS RD_CURS CURSOR FOR
        SELECT 1  -- from VT_C
    DO
    SET V_REPORT_DATE =1 ;
end for l1;
```

end;

But when I refer to `VT_C` table inside loop TD throws such error:

> REPLACE PROCEDURE Failed.  [5526] SPL1027:E(L15), Missing/Invalid SQL statement'E(3807):Object 'VT_C' does not exist.'.

What is wrong here?

Database version: Teradata 15.10.07.08

Provider version: Teradata.Net 16.10.0.0

Tried ANSI and Default Session Mode - same error

UPD. I found possible solution, manually create volatile tables, then procedure will be created with just warnings. What is going on

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Store the result of a select statement within a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24185966/store-the-result-of-a-select-statement-within-a-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@RobPaller answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24185966/store-the-result-of-a-select-statement-within-a-stored-procedure). Have we considered a global temporary table?

The table definition is stored in the DBC data dictionary and instantiated for the duration of the session when referenced by SQL. Like a volatile table the global temporary table is session specific. Unlike a volatile table, a global temporary table relies on the user's temporary space instead of spool space.

Or just manually create volatile tables, then procedure will be created with just warnings